# Best Practice for handling collection updates in .net-maui (MVVM)

Tags: mvvm, maui

I have been working with MVVM and `ObservableCollections` for some time now, but it is still not clear to me what is the best practice for handling an update of a collection. When I add an item to the collection the UI gets notified and shows the new item in e.g. a `ListView`.
But I cannot see how this process works for the update of an item in the Collection. What I do now is to completely re-assign the collection and raise an `OnPropertyChanged` event but this updates the whole collection which seems like overkill and not really efficient.

Example use-case: The user edits an item and I want the change to be presented in the List or the Collection receives an update from a different service like a SignalR message.

I tried to assign new Values to an item of the `ObservableCollection` but it seems not to update the View even if I raise the `OnPropertyChanged` Event

Comment: The most quick and simple way - replace the item with a modified one.

Comment: if you are updating the properties of an item in the collection, that item's class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (or use `ObservableObject`/`ObservableProperty`)

Comment: @Json: As an example if I have an `ObservableCollection<string>` that holds a List of names I would need to change it to `ObservableCollection<MyNameClassImplementingINotifyPropertyChanged>` and raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged`  event in that new class if I update the Name Property?

Comment: Yes, although if you really just have a collection of strings that might not be necessary.  In that case just removing the old value and adding a new one might be easiest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From document [From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm),we could know that:

> ViewModels generally implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface,
> which means that the class fires a PropertyChanged event whenever one
> of its properties changes. The data binding mechanism in Xamarin.Forms
> attaches a handler to this PropertyChanged event so it can be notified
> when a property changes and keep the target updated with the new
> value.

So if you want the UI updates automatically once changing the value of the property of the Item model in your List, you can implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your item model.

You can refer to the following code:

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{       
    private string _numType;
    public string NumType
    {
        get => _numType;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _numType, value);
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }


    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Note:**

1.Suppose you want to update UI automatically while modifying the value of `NumType`,you can add following code:

```
    private string _numType;
    public string NumType
    {
        get => _numType;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _numType, value);
        }
    }
```

2.If you want UI update automatically after adding or remove item from your datalist, you just define your list as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
```

For more information, check [ObservableCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0).

Comment: although I knew all of that I guess I just needed another push in the right direction. It works as Expected. Thanks